# In SQL how to select tuples whose "character varying(5)" column values are fixed size?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have this table with a zipcode column(zipcode character varying(5)) but some of "bad" rows have invalid zipcode like "9000" or "2". and I want all the tuples whose zipcode values have exactly 5 characters.

How to translate

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE zipcode "is size 5"
```

to SQL?

I am using postgresql btw.

Comment: use `length` function

Comment: And char_length is the ANSI SQL version. (No dbms specified...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE zipcode like "_____"
```

(Five underscores)

OR

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LENGTH(Trim(zipcode)) = 5
```

`LENGTH` function in postgresql

Comment: what if a data like this `____5` or `__5__`

Comment: Oh... You meant leading and trailing spaces...? then I can use 'trim' function too :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you've data like below

```
zipcode 
------- 
  5     
    5   
900 5   
900 2   
900     
90025   
68656
```

so you need to use `trim()` function else no need to use `trim()`, just `char_length(zipcode)=5;` or `length(zipcode)=5;` is enough.

```
SELECT * 
FROM zips 
WHERE length(trim(zipcode)) =5
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM zips 
WHERE char_length(trim(zipcode))=5
```

> **trim(string)**:- Remove the longest string containing only the characters (a
>   space by  default)
>                       from the start/end/both ends of the string
>
> **length(string**):- returns the length of the string *measured in bytes*.
>
> **char_length(string)** or **character_length(string)**:- returns the length of the string *measured in
>   characters*.